# How to initialize a collection of records?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SET serveroutput ON;

DECLARE
    TYPE enreg IS RECORD 
    (mot varchar(30),sig varchar(30));

    TYPE tab IS TABLE OF enreg;
    t tab := tab({'html','html'},{'css','css'});

BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(t(1).mot) ;
END;
```

Comment: Can you add some description of your requirement? Posting just code is not very helpful to other people reading you question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i went to  initialize the tabel with  tab({'html','html'},{'css','css'});

Comment: i went to initialize it in the declaee section not in the begin like t(1).mot:='html',t(1).dig:='html' !!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize RECORDS, they are initialized automatically. You can set values for example like this:

```
DECLARE

    TYPE enreg IS RECORD (mot VARCHAR(30),sig VARCHAR(30));

    en1 enreg;
    en2 enreg;

    TYPE TAB IS TABLE OF enreg;
    t TAB;

BEGIN

    en1.mot := 'html';
    en1.sig := 'html';
    en2.mot := 'css';
    en2.sig := 'css';
    t := TAB(en1, en2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( t(1).mot) ;

    SELECT 'html', 'html'
    INTO en1
    FROM dual;  
    SELECT 'css', 'css'
    INTO en2
    FROM dual;
    t := TAB(en1, en2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( t(1).mot) ;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

> i went to initialize it in the declaee section not in the begin like `t(1).mot:='html', t(1).sig:='html'` !!

You can do it in the `DECLARE` section of the block, if you have a function that will populate the record:

```
SET ServerOutPut ON;

DECLARE
  TYPE enreg IS RECORD (mot varchar(30),sig varchar(30));
  TYPE tab IS TABLE OF enreg;
  FUNCTION createEnreg( mot VARCHAR2, sig VARCHAR2 ) RETURN enreg;

  t TAB := TAB( createEnreg('html','html'), createEnreg('css','css') );

  FUNCTION createEnreg( mot VARCHAR2, sig VARCHAR2 ) RETURN enreg
  IS
    e enreg;
  BEGIN
    e.mot := mot;
    e.sig := sig;
    RETURN e;
  END;

BEGIN
  Dbms_output.put_line(t(1).mot) ;
END;
/
```